# How to match 2 huge size list #2

Tags: python, list

I got a precious answer from Vishal Balaji who suggested me on to use of `set()` for improve speed in **list intersection**. For whom can't understand what does mean [intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection) , here is the link  ;-).

```
delta = list(set(tit_comp)-set(out))
```

this helped me a lot, but now I need a further step up in velocity, because the lists to manage are in order of over 10^6 items(strings **of max #10 char**) each and the computing time is becoming **incommensurabile** (always for whom don't know it: means to much time to be count that imply the above  intersection take too to long time to wait it finish for a reasonable time)..
Even splitting the list in chunk the computing time is huge. I also facing with a `mem overflow crash`
any suggestion on how to solve the enpass ?

I'm finally asking if anyone knows a different way to treat the huge lists..

thanks

Comment: Please read [ask] and explain: what should happen when you run the code - what do you mean by "matching" the lists? Where does the data come from? How long are the individual strings? How is "splitting the list in chunks" supposed to help?

Comment: if you can use lists with different order then you can sort lists and split into files - file wit all words starting at char `A`, file with all words starting at `B`, etc. then you could compare smaller files.

Comment: if you can't change order in files then you may have to buy faster computer with more RAM, or use servers in cloud - Google, Amazon, Microsoft, etc.

Comment: I'm wandering: maybe if you would put list in database then it could do it faster because databases may have optimized algorithms. Or maybe you should at least try with Python module `pandas` which uses code created in C/C++ and it may work faster.

Comment: thks furas for your comments. put list into db would be further next step..but not only the list, the whole project's data storage. Now I'm concentrate on the core